# Java Null value

Tags: java, null

I have one main class that says

```
Students registeredStudent = null;
```

I have to write Students class myself since its not given. I cant seem to figure what' s registeredStudent value in Students class. Currently I have Students class as follow -

```
public class Students {
String name;
String id;
//boolean selectedStudent;
public Students(String id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;

}

public void display(){
    System.out.println("ID : " + id);
    System.out.println("Name of Student :" + name);

}
}
```

public class DrivingSchool {

```
private Autocar [] ac = new Autocar[10];
private Motorbike [] m = new Motorbike[10];
private Manualcar [] mc = new Manualcar[10];

private Students [] s = new Students[30];

public void start(){
    String[]menu = {"Display all vehicles", "Display all students",
            "Register a new student", "Assign student an auto car", "Assign student a manual car",
            "Assign student a motorbike","Deregister a student"};

    while(true){
        int choice = Keyboard.readInt("Enter Your Choice >");
        if(choice == 1){
            displayAllV();
        }
        else if(choice == 2){

        }
        else if(choice == 3){

        }
        else if(choice == 4){

        }
        else if(choice == 5){

        }
        else if(choice == 6){

        }
        else if(choice == 7){

        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }



}
public void displayAllV(){
    for(int i = 0;i < ac.length; i++){
        if(ac[i] != null){
        ac[i].display();
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j<m.length; j++){
        if(m[j] != null){
            m[j].display();
        }
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < mc.length; x++){
        if(mc[x]!=null){
            mc[x].display();
        }
    }
}
public void displayAllStud(){
    boolean hasStud = false;
    for(int i = 0;i < s.length; i++){
        if(s[i] != null){
            s[i].display();
            hasStud = true;
        }
    }
    if(!hasStud){
        System.out.println("No Student Registered");
    }
}

public void registerStud(){
    String id = Keyboard.readString("Enter Student ID :");
    for(int i = 0;i < s.length; i++){
        if(s[i]!= null && id.equals(s[i].id)){
            System.out.println("Student with this ID already exist");
        return;
        }
    }
    boolean registered = false;
    for(int i =0;i < s.length; i++){
        if(s[i] == null){
            String name = Keyboard.readString("Enter Student name :");
            s[i] = new Students(id, name);
            System.out.println("A new student is registered.");
            registered = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!registered){
        System.out.println("Unable to register. School is full");
    }
}

    public void assignAutoCar(){
        String id = Keyboard.readString("Enter Student ID :");
        Students selectedStudent = null;

        for(int i =0; i<s.length; i++){
            if(s[i] != null && id.equals(s[i].id)){
                selectedStudent = s[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if(selectedStudent != null && selectedStudent.autocar == null){
for(int i =0; i < ac.length; i++){
                if(ac[i].isVehicleAvailable()){
                    ac[i].setAvail(false);
                    selectedStudent.autoCar = ac[i];
                    break;
                }
    }
    public void createVehicles(){
        ac[0] = new Autocar("LA1", 4);
        ac[1] = new Autocar("LA2", 4);
        ac[2] = new Autocar("LA3", 4);
        ac[3] = new Autocar("LA4", 4);
        ac[4] = new Autocar("LA5", 4);

        mc[0] = new Manualcar("LM1", 4, 5);
        mc[1] = new Manualcar("LM2", 4, 5);
        mc[2] = new Manualcar("LM3", 4, 5);
        mc[3] = new Manualcar("LM4", 4, 5);
        mc[4] = new Manualcar("LM5", 4, 5);

        m[0] = new Motorbike("M1", 2);
        m[1] = new Motorbike("M2", 2);
        m[2] = new Motorbike("M3", 3);
        m[3] = new Motorbike("M4", 3);
        m[4] = new Motorbike("M5", 4);
    }



}
```

Comment: So what help you needed from SO Users ? Even its hard to figure what all variable/methods declare inside that class.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You said `registeredStudent` is a variable in your main class. Therefore, it's *not* in the Students class, because it's somewhere else...

Comment: @immibis Look Like he wants someone will write Student class for him.

Comment: registeredStudent in Main class would represent one instance/object of Student class  so example Student registeredStudent = new Student("1","Austin"); and then call registeredStudent.display();

Comment: @SubodhJoshi no mate.. I m writing the class on my own. But I cant figure out what type of variable the registeredStudent is in Students class. This is the full method in the main class that use registeredStudent variable. You can see it in assignAutoCar method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay first of all, registeredStudent is not a part of your Students class.

This assignment:

```
Students registeredStudent = null;
```

Which is in main method, says: Hey, I want registeredStudent to be a local variable, which is a reference to a Students type (your class) object , and currently make it point to null.

You could make registeredStudent point to an actual Students object with this:

```
registeredStudent = new Students("1", "Mike");
```

So now, the registeredStudent points to a new Students object, that has the id 1 and the name Mike.

Therefore registeredStudent is not part of the Students class. It is just a local variable in main method.

(Note: You d better name your classes on Singular form: eg. Student instead of Students. When you want to create a new student object, new Student(...) makes more sense than new Students(...)

Comment: Thanks for your information bro... I m still a beginner in Java..  :D

Comment: Np. We were all beginners once. Keep going! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the main class you have to pass registered student id and student name in the contructor of `Student` class like :

```
Student registeredStudent = new  Student (1,"Austin");
registeredStudent.display();
```

Comment: Thank you Rehman.. I have been finding out how i should write registeredStudent in my Student class..

Comment: Hi .. Now I saw this line of code in my main class. 
    if(selectedStudent != null && selectedStudent.autocar == null)
I cant seem to get ".autocar" . Is it a method ?

Comment: Done bro.. DrivingSchool is the main

Comment: That line doesnt make any sense since its not doing anything in that if block. But basically its checking whether student is having autocar or not

Comment: I have finish writing down the method.. But i dont know what does ".autocar" do in Students class. I m having an error in my main class saying "autocar cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: It should be `selectedStudent.ac`. not `selectedStudent.autocar`

Comment: No idea why its written like this. `Students` class doesnt have any variable named `autocar`

Answer (score 0):

registeredStudent is just reference of Student type and its value is null. If you want to create Student object than don't change your Students class and in your main class write

```
Students registeredStudent = new Student("someId","someName");
//after this you can use your display() method
registeredStudent.display();
```